# error: static assertion failed: template argument must be a complete class or an unbounded array

Tags: c++, inheritance, c++17, using-directives, template-instantiation

I'm deriving from a base class in which I try to define a type. That type is dependent on itself via a variant, so it would require to know the memory layout of the base class upon definition. However, I'm not prematurely defining the type? So I thought this would work but it doesnt ([CompilerExplorer](https://godbolt.org/#g:!((g:!((g:!((h:codeEditor,i:(filename:%271%27,fontScale:14,fontUsePx:%270%27,j:1,lang:c%2B%2B,selection:(endColumn:2,endLineNumber:26,positionColumn:2,positionLineNumber:26,selectionStartColumn:2,selectionStartLineNumber:26,startColumn:2,startLineNumber:26),source:%27%23include+%3Cvariant%3E%0A%23include+%3Ccstddef%3E%0A%23include+%3Carray%3E%0A%0A%0Atemplate+%3Csize_t+V%3E+struct+container_base%3B%0Atemplate+%3Csize_t+V%3E+struct+container%3B%0A%0Atemplate+%3Csize_t+V%3E%0Ausing+val+%3D+std::variant%3Cstd::monostate,+int,+container_base%3CV%3E%3E%3B%0A%0Atemplate+%3Csize_t+V%3E%0Astruct+container_base%0A%7B%0A++++using+iterator+%3D+typename+std::array%3Cval%3CV%3E,+V%3E::iterator%3B%0A%7D%3B%0A%0Atemplate+%3Csize_t+V%3E%0Astruct+container+:+public+container_base%3CV%3E%0A%7B%0A%7D%3B%0A%0Aint+main()%0A%7B%0A++++container%3C100%3E+A%3B%0A%7D%27),l:%275%27,n:%270%27,o:%27C%2B%2B+source+%231%27,t:%270%27)),k:50,l:%274%27,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,s:0,t:%270%27),(g:!((g:!((h:compiler,i:(compiler:gsnapshot,filters:(b:%270%27,binary:%271%27,commentOnly:%270%27,demangle:%270%27,directives:%270%27,execute:%270%27,intel:%270%27,libraryCode:%270%27,trim:%271%27),flagsViewOpen:%271%27,fontScale:14,fontUsePx:%270%27,j:1,lang:c%2B%2B,libs:!(),options:%27--std%3Dc%2B%2B17+-O0%27,selection:(endColumn:1,endLineNumber:1,positionColumn:1,positionLineNumber:1,selectionStartColumn:1,selectionStartLineNumber:1,startColumn:1,startLineNumber:1),source:1,tree:%271%27),l:%275%27,n:%270%27,o:%27x86-64+gcc+(trunk)+(C%2B%2B,+Editor+%231,+Compiler+%231)%27,t:%270%27)),k:50,l:%274%27,m:43.35736354273945,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,s:0,t:%270%27),(g:!((h:output,i:(compilerName:%27x86-64+clang+(trunk)%27,editorid:1,fontScale:14,fontUsePx:%270%27,j:1,wrap:%271%27),l:%275%27,n:%270%27,o:%27Output+of+x86-64+gcc+(trunk)+(Compiler+%231)%27,t:%270%27)),header:(),l:%274%27,m:56.64263645726055,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,s:0,t:%270%27)),k:50,l:%273%27,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,t:%270%27)),l:%272%27,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,t:%270%27)),version:4)):

```
#include <variant>
#include <cstddef>
#include <array>


template <size_t V> struct container_base;
template <size_t V> struct container;

template <size_t V>
using val = std::variant<std::monostate, int, container_base<V>>;

template <size_t V>
struct container_base
{
    using iterator = typename std::array<val<V>, V>::iterator;
};

template <size_t V>
struct container : public container_base<V>
{
};

int main()
{
    container<100> A;
}
```

This yields:

```
In file included from /opt/compiler-explorer/gcc-trunk-20220726/include/c++/13.0.0/variant:37,
                 from <source>:1:
/opt/compiler-explorer/gcc-trunk-20220726/include/c++/13.0.0/type_traits: In instantiation of 'struct std::is_copy_constructible<container_base<100> >':
/opt/compiler-explorer/gcc-trunk-20220726/include/c++/13.0.0/type_traits:3202:33:   required from 'constexpr const bool std::is_copy_constructible_v<container_base<100> >'
/opt/compiler-explorer/gcc-trunk-20220726/include/c++/13.0.0/variant:329:5:   required from 'constexpr const bool std::__detail::__variant::_Traits<std::monostate, int, container_base<100> >::_S_copy_ctor'
/opt/compiler-explorer/gcc-trunk-20220726/include/c++/13.0.0/variant:1334:11:   required from 'class std::variant<std::monostate, int, container_base<100> >'
/opt/compiler-explorer/gcc-trunk-20220726/include/c++/13.0.0/array:109:55:   required from 'struct std::array<std::variant<std::monostate, int, container_base<100> >, 100>'
<source>:15:11:   required from 'struct container_base<100>'
<source>:19:8:   required from 'struct container<100>'
<source>:25:20:   required from here
/opt/compiler-explorer/gcc-trunk-20220726/include/c++/13.0.0/type_traits:1012:52: error: static assertion failed: template argument must be a complete class or an unbounded array
 1012 |       static_assert(std::__is_complete_or_unbounded(__type_identity<_Tp>{}),
      |
```

I understand it so that variant needs a complete type to work with when it's first used (which is in main! But the type is complete until then, so I don't know why it doesn't work. What can I do to fix this?

Comment: I@AlanBirtles I know about members but is this also true for types? They don't contribute to the memory layout after all

Comment: `typename std::array<val<V>, V>::iterator` requires `val<V>` to be complete. But this can't happen because, at that point, `container_base<V>` (which `val<V>` depends upon) has not been defined. If you define `container_base<V>::iterator = val<V>*`, your code compiles.

Comment: @paolo Thanks makes sense. What are the C++ rules for qualified access (::)? Does the qualifier always have to be defineable at this point?

Comment: "**[res.on.functions]/2** In particular, the effects are undefined in the following cases: ... (2.5) — If an incomplete type is used as a template argument when instantiating a template component or evaluating a concept, unless specifically allowed for that component." Accessing `std::array<val<V>, V>::iterator` requires instantiating `std::array<val<V>, V>`, which requires instantiating `val<V>`, which requires instantiating `std::variant<std::monostate, int, container_base<V>>`, and `container_base<V>` is at that point an incomplete type.